# Equality of eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 100\sqrt{2}&x&0\\-x&0&-x\\0&x&100\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $x>0$ has two equal eigenvalues. What is the value of $x$?
It is the question. I tried by getting the characteristic equation

$$(-\lambda)^3+200\sqrt{2}(-\lambda)^2+2(x^2+100^2)(-\lambda)+200\sqrt{2}x^2=0$$

which must be equivalent to

$$(\lambda-\alpha)^2(\lambda-\beta)=0$$

where $\alpha,\beta$ are the eigenvalues. I cannot proceed further. Help solicited.

Answer (score 4):

If you follow that line of thinking, the matrix has two equal eigenvalues if and only if its characteristic polynomial has a repeated root. This happens if and only if the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is 0. The discriminant of the characteristic polynomial is $80000x^4 - 32x^6$ and if $x > 0$ then the only solution is $x = 50$.

Alternatively, you can solve the characteristic polynomial directly. This gives you roots at $t = 100\sqrt 2, 50 \sqrt 2 \pm \sqrt{5000 - 2x^2}$. If you select two of them and equate them you will get $x = 0, \pm 50$ depending on which two you select.

Comment: Is there any other method?

Comment: @Purushothaman I edited a new solution into my original answer. It might be possible that there is a more clever way to solve this but I don't see it. In particular, I don't think this problem can be done by hand easily.